# typescript - Assign object to array

Tags: typescript

I want assign an object to an array, but i have this error in assign function

> Expected at least 1 arguments, but got 1 or more

```
var obj1 = [{ abc: 'abc value' }];

var obj2 = { def: 'new def value'};

var obj3 = Object.assign(...obj1 , obj2) ;
```

Comment: What is the expected outcome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use array spreading in this case, `Object.assign` is used to copy  all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object, so it's not useful in this case.

Take note that array spreading will **shallow** copy the values of `obj1` in the new array with `obj2` being put as the last element.

```
var obj3 = [...obj1, obj2];
```

If you are targeting IE then you can use:

```
var obj3 = obj1.slice();
obj3.push(obj2);
```

Note: Array spreading doesn't work on IE.

From MDN on `Object.assign`:

> The Object.assign() method copies all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object. It returns the target object.

[Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

[Array spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Object.assign chaining as below

```
var obj1 = [{ abc: 'abc value' }];
var obj2 = { def: 'new def value' };
var obj3 = Object.assign(Object.assign({}, ...obj1), obj2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are trying to do, your method could result in unexpected copying.

```
const obj1 = [{ abc: 'abc value' }, { abc: 'abc value at index 2' }];
const obj3 = Object.assign(...obj1 , obj2);
```

will result the last item in the array to override any previous values set where there are matching keys.

```
{ abc: 'abc value at index 2', def: 'new def value' }
```

if you are looking to copy something to all objects in the array, you want to use `.map()` over the array of objects.

```
const obj1 = [{ abc: 'abc value' }, { abc: 'abc value at index 2' }];
const obj3 = obj1.map(obj => Object.assign(obj, obj2));
```